# test inside flask app whether 'flask db init' was ever run

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, sqlalchemy

I created a variable up the top of a script under the imports within an app context. Some functions in the script use the variable and it is also imported into other scripts. The variable is actually a call to a class method from an imported instance, which possibly also invokes 'session'

```
with app.app_context():
    myvariable = myinstance.session.method3
```

No problems with anything, but somebody just decided to start afresh on their PC and run

```
flask db init
```

It didn't like that. `flask db init` is only run once usually then not again for years if something crashes. I don't want to write a hack that just checks for the presence of a .db file, but is there a method in flask or sqlalchemy which will give you a True or a False as to whether the init was ever run?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, I spoke about not checking for a file in the question, but have realised that the *directory* 'migrations' does not exist before that command is run, so unless someone has a better idea will go with

```
import os

if os.path.isdir('migrations'):
    print("init was run")
else:
    print("init has never been run")
```

The name 'migrations' is not something I chose myself so is a somewhat clean solution.